# Explicit construction of the Drinfeld double for quasi-bialgebras

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, drinfeld-center

Let $A$ be a quasi-bialgebra over a field $k$ and $A$-$\mathrm{mod}$ be the category of finite dimensional left $A$-modules. Since $A$-$\mathrm{mod}$ is a  monoidal category, its Drinfel’d center $\mathcal{Z}(A$-$\mathrm{mod)}$ is a braided monoidal category. So we obtain quasi triangular quasi-bialgebra $D(A)$ from $\mathcal{Z}(A$-$\mathrm{mod)}$ by using tannaka duality.

**Question** : Is there an explicit construction of $D(A)$?